# Deconstruct props while adding props to it. - Is it possible?

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have some props like this.

```
const {
  header,
  footer,
  name,
  body,
  title,
} = this.props;
```

All works great but is there a way I can assign name to body in the above syntax without having to later assign it.

Something like.

```
const {
  header,
  footer,
  name,
  body: {...name},
  title,
} = this.props;
```

**Remember** I want to keep whats in body but add slug to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming

```
const this = {
    props: {
        header: 'header',
        footer: 'footer',
        name: 'name',
        body: 'body',
        title: 'title',
    }
};
```

I think this is what you are wanting to achieve....

```
const {
    header,
    footer,
    name,
    body,
    title,
} = {
  ...this.props,
  body: this.props.name,
  //if body is an object, and name is an object, and you want to merge the two you can do:
  /** 
   * body: { ...this.props.body, ...this.props.name }
   */
};

console.log(body); //"name"
```

but seems much simpler to do

```
const {
    header,
    footer,
    name,
    title,
} = this.props;

const body = this.props.name; 
// or if you are merging
/**
 * const body = { ...this.props.body, ...name };
 */
```

But as far as you sample, no you can no refer to a key in an object while it's being defined (or deconstructed).

```
const {
  header,
  footer,
  name,
  body: {...name}, //name is not available here, but this.props.name is
  //also `body: {...name}` is the same as `body: name`
  title,
} = this.props;
```

Answer (score 1):

To give the `body` a custom name:

```js
const {
  header,
  footer,
  name,
  body: customName,
  title,
} = this.props;

console.log(customName);
```

To compose the `body` and `name` props into a single `body` const:

```js
const this.props = {
  name: { name1: 1, name2: 2 },
  body: { body1: 3, body2: 4 }
};

const {
  header,
  footer,
  name,
  body,
  title,
} = {
  ...this.props,
  body: { ...this.props.body, ...this.props.name }
};

console.log(body);
```

Comment: Right that's giving body a custom name but thats not what I was asked, but thanks anyway. What I'm asking is can I assign body extra properties like name for example all in that shorthand syntax

Comment: Sorry, didn't get you correctly first. Updated the answer.